# Declaring Global Variables in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm an Arduino newbie. I'm trying to read all of the analog and digital pins on my UNO and output to a python script over serial. I'm getting an error that variables D2-D12 are not declared in this scope. Variables a0 - a5 do not report an error. I know I must be overlooking something really simple.

```
byte APins[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
byte DPins[] = {D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, D11, D12};

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  for (int x = 2; x < 13; x++){    
    Serial.print("A");
    Serial.print(x);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(analogRead(APins[x]));

  }

  for (int x = 2; x < 13; x++){    
    Serial.print("D");
    Serial.print(x);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(DPins[x-2]));

    delay(250);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following

```
byte DPins[] = {D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, D11, D12};
```

to

```
byte DPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

The is no `D` prefix Digital Pins. It is just Decimal Number.